nearest_int and make_qx_quants from llama.cpp
code is from ggml-quants.c of llama.cpp.
https://github.com/ggerganov/llama.cpp/blob/master/ggml/src/ggml-quants.c
How does the following code work? where does the magic number 4194303.f and 12582912.f come from?
static inline int nearest_int(float fval) {
    assert(fabsf(fval) <= 4194303.f);
    float val = fval + 12582912.f;
    int i; memcpy(&i, &val, sizeof(int));
    return (i & 0x007fffff) - 0x00400000;
}

In the same file, regarding make_qx_quants. It is not clear what it is doing. Especially sumlx and suml2. Any pointer about the algorithm behind the code?
static float make_qx_quants(int n, int nmax, const float * restrict x, int8_t * restrict L, int rmse_type,
        const float * restrict qw) {
    float max = 0;
    float amax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        float ax = fabsf(x[i]);
        if (ax > amax) { amax = ax; max = x[i]; }
    }
    if (amax < GROUP_MAX_EPS) { // all zero
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            L[i] = 0;
        }
        return 0.f;
    }
    float iscale = -nmax / max;
    if (rmse_type == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int l = nearest_int(iscale * x[i]);
            L[i] = nmax + MAX(-nmax, MIN(nmax-1, l));
        }
        return 1/iscale;
    }
    bool return_early = false;
    if (rmse_type < 0) {
        rmse_type = -rmse_type;
        return_early = true;
    }
    float sumlx = 0;
    float suml2 = 0;
#ifdef HAVE_BUGGY_APPLE_LINKER
    // use 'volatile' to prevent unroll and work around a bug in Apple ld64 1015.7
    for (volatile int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
#else
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
#endif
        int l = nearest_int(iscale * x[i]);
        l = MAX(-nmax, MIN(nmax-1, l));
        L[i] = l + nmax;
        float w = qw ? qw[i] : rmse_type == 1 ? x[i] * x[i] : rmse_type == 2 ? 1 : rmse_type == 3 ? fabsf(x[i]) : sqrtf(fabsf(x[i]));
        sumlx += w*x[i]*l;
        suml2 += w*l*l;
    }
    float scale = suml2 ? sumlx/suml2 : 0.0f;
    if (return_early) return suml2 > 0 ? 0.5f*(scale + 1/iscale) : 1/iscale;
    float best = scale * sumlx;
    for (int is = -9; is <= 9; ++is) {
        if (is == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        iscale = -(nmax + 0.1f*is) / max;
        sumlx = suml2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int l = nearest_int(iscale * x[i]);
            l = MAX(-nmax, MIN(nmax-1, l));
            float w = qw ? qw[i] : rmse_type == 1 ? x[i] * x[i] : rmse_type == 2 ? 1 : rmse_type == 3 ? fabsf(x[i]) : sqrtf(fabsf(x[i]));
            sumlx += w*x[i]*l;
            suml2 += w*l*l;
        }
        if (suml2 > 0 && sumlx*sumlx > best*suml2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                int l = nearest_int(iscale * x[i]);
                L[i] = nmax + MAX(-nmax, MIN(nmax-1, l));
            }
            scale = sumlx/suml2; best = scale*sumlx;
        }
    }
    return scale;
}

